# Admin backend, show post from a category and exclude the posts from subcategories

Tags: php, categories, wp-admin

In the www.myexample.com/wp-admin/edit.php?category_name=mycat I want to see only the posts which are in mycat and not in its subcategories.

Any hint on how to achieve it?

Here is what I've tried at the moment:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'filter_post_edit_screen' );

function filter_post_edit_screen($query) {
    global $pagenow, $wp_query;

    $category_name = $wp_query->get( 'category_name' );

    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' &&  !empty($category_name)){

        var_dump($category_name);

        // Get children categories of current cat if they exist
        if ( $excludes = get_categories( "child_of=" . $category_name ) ) {

            var_dump($excludes);

            // For each child, add just the ID to an array
            foreach ( $excludes as $key => $value ) {
                $exs[] = $value->term_taxonomy_id;
            }
        }

        // If array exists, remove posts in child categories from query.
        if ( isset( $exs ) && is_array( $exs ) ) {

            // WP Query changed in 3.1
            $query->query_vars['category__not_in'] = $exs;
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by subfolder? hierarchical?

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla: yes,. I don't want posts which are in the subcategories

Comment: if the category is animals and subcategories are cat,lion etc..showing only animals without cat,lion ..does not make a  sense :)

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla: in my case it makes a lot of sense... but however I appreciate filosofy but I prefer programming :D

Comment: `$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'parent' => 0
);
$categories = get_categories($args);`